# Transform Keyword in VBA

Tags: c#, vba, pivot, transform

I am currently converting a VBA application to C# and i have come across a query with the keyword `transform` and i am unsure what the whole query is doing. Can anyone help? Below is the code.

Thanks in advance!

```
TRANSFORM SUM(NUM)
SELECT [X]
FROM table
GROUP BY [X]
PIVOT [Date];
```

Comment: why would the query change? you are converting the code not the query that's run. Has the RDBMS chnaged as well?

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208956(v=office.12).aspx) to the rescue

Comment: Hi Mitch, Sorry i should have explained that i am also recreating the database using sql on a different server hence why i am rewriting the queries in sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/transform-statement-HP001032277.aspx) shows that Transform is an Access keyword, defining a Pivot query. Search engines are great!